# Java JDBC General SQL insert function

Tags: java, mysql, sql, jdbc, arraylist

I am writing a generic function to insert data into SQLtables and I am wondering how to improve my current implementation.

My current function looks like:

```
public void insertIntoDatabase(String table, ArrayList<String> insertRow) {
..
}
```

table - Name of the SQL table
insertRow - ArrayList of values to insert

Some tables also contain other attributes than VARCHARS so I am considering `ArrayList<xtable> insertRow`
But is it necessary to write individual java classes for each database table ?

Thanks for your help!
M

Comment: why don't you use then hibernate ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't bind table or column names in `PreparedStatement`.

But it is possible to write a generic DAO:

```
package persistence;

public interface GenericDao<K, V> {
    List<V> find();
    V find(K id);
    K save(V value);
    void update(V value);
    void delete(V value);
};
```

Comment: Thanks . One solution I found here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10872919/separating-sql-from-the-java-code