# How to add variables to xml properties file?

Tags: java, sql, spring

I'm trying to externalize SQL statements for usage with `spring`, as advised in https://stackoverflow.com/a/24141382/1194415.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">

<properties>
    <entry key="SQL_MAX_ID">
        <![CDATA[
            SELECT MAX(id) FROM mytable
        ]]>
    </entry>
</properties>
```

Question: when having multiple sql statements, it would be nice to define `mytable` only once, and then refer to it as some kind of variable.

Is that possible in a simple properties file?

I'm loading the file as follows:

```
@Bean
public PropertiesFactoryBean sql() {
    PropertiesFactoryBean bean = new PropertiesFactoryBean();
    bean.setLocation(new ClassPathResource("sql.xml"));
    return bean;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The recommended way to store properties in spring projects is to use property file, in your property file application.properties file under src/main/resources and have your property defined there

```
table=mytable
```

Then use JSTL to access it in your xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE properties SYSTEM "http://java.sun.com/dtd/properties.dtd">

<properties>
  <entry key="SQL_MAX_ID">
    <![CDATA[
        SELECT MAX(id) FROM ${table}
    ]]>
</entry>
</properties>
```

Comment: Does not work unfortunately. The `${table}` statement remains as is and is not replaced by content is application.properties. Maybe I have to load the file in a different way (see the `@Bean` in my question)?