# confusion : string is immutable so don't use for concatenation

Tags: java, string, concatenation

JAVA : I want to clear that using String like this

```
String str = " SELECT "
           + "field1, "
           + "field2, "
           + "field3  "
           + " FROM table1; ";
```

is *okay* or *not* to use this way.

asking based on best practice regarding **String** not to use for **concatenation**.

THIS IS VERY SHORT QUERY BUT ACTUALLY WE HAVE VERY VERY LARGE QUERY. THIS IS JUST EXAMPLE. SO JUST WANT TO CONFIRM I AM NOT DOING ANY THING WRONG.

Comment: What exactly are you concerned about? That doesn't look terribly readable to me, but it's a compile-time constant, so the concatenation isn't going to happen at execution time... using a StringBuilder will make the performance of this *worse*, if anything. Even if the concatenation *were* performed at execution time, it's very unlikely that concatenating a few strings like this will be significant compared with executing a SQL query (which is presumably the context). Concatenation *in a loop* is usually a bad idea, improved with StringBuilder - but that's a different matter.

Comment: @JonSkeet if the question is about a predefined data concatenation then you are right

Comment: THIS IS VERY SHORT QUERY BUT ACTUALLY WE HAVE VERY VERY LARGE QUERY. THIS IS JUST EXAMPLE. SO JUST WANT TO CONFIRM I AM NOT DOING ANY THING WRONG.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is okay and is exactly the same as writing it as one string:

```
String str = " SELECT field1, field2, field3   FROM table1; ";
```

If you are concatenating string literals, the compiler will do the concatenation at compile time, so the resulting bytecode is exactly the same, no matter if you write it like you did or as one string literal.

Comment: but others are saying it creates StringBuilder object for every concatenation.

Comment: @murtaza.webdev Well, the others are wrong... if you want proof, compile your code and then decompile it with the `javap` tool that is included in the JDK. Note: I'm specifically talking about concatenating string **literals**. Ofcourse if you're not really concatenating literals, then the answer is different. (Note that none of the other answers are disagreeing with what I said - read them carefully...).

Answer (score 3):

`String` concatenation with the `+` operator can be deemed as a bad practice in certain contexts, i.e. if it can't be automatically replaced by `StringBuilder` invocations at compile-time.

In general, if your field is a constant or initialized only once anyway, then `String` concatenation with `+` is perfectly fine.

However, if you are dynamically building `String`s and looping / recursing, you are better off with a `StringBuilder` (or a `StringBuffer` for thread-safe concatenations).

Comment: what u say about @jesper 's answer

Comment: @murtaza.webdev I think Jesper's answer is only partially correct. If your field is a constant or initialized only once, hence resulting in a `String` that is concatenated with `+` only once with literals or constants, the compiler will replace it with its concatenated value. Not, however, if part of your concatenation is variable. In which case the compiler may use a `StringBuilder` instead, or leave the concatenation as is, depending on the complexity.

Answer (score 1):

I highly doubt that field1 and field2 and table1 are known upfront, I assume they come as parameters to some function.

In that case you *should* be using a StringBuilder instead. Even if you concat with plus sign, you will still (almost always) get a StringBuilder, just look at the bytecode. Here is a reference :

> *"An implementation may choose to perform conversion and concatenation in one step to avoid creating and then discarding an intermediate String object. To increase the performance of repeated string concatenation, a Java compiler may use the StringBuffer class or a similar technique to reduce the number of intermediate String objects that are created by evaluation of an expression."*  .[15.18.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.18.1)

Just remember that there will be a performance penalty if you will loop.

Comment: what u say about @jesper 's answer

Comment: @murtaza.webdev jesper is right. The issue here is : Do you know field1, filed2, etc upfront? Or do you accept them as parameters to a method?

Answer (score 1):

Your example is fine because it only involves *literals*, and the compiler will do the concatenation at compile-time.

---

But if you had:

```
String str = " SELECT "
           + "field1, "
           + someVariable
           + "field3  "
           + " FROM table1; ";
```

...then the compiler would only be able to handle part of it for you, resulting in this at runtime:

```
String str = " SELECT field1, "
           + someVariable
           + "field3   FROM table1; ";
```

The way it happens at runtime is via `StringBuilder`, which sounds great, but sadly is done fairly inefficiently, in effect it's:

```
StringBuilder sb1 = new StringBuilder();
sb1.append(" SELECT field1, ");
sb1.append(someVariable);
String temp = sb1.toString();
StringBuilder sb2 = new StringBuilder();
sb2.append(temp);
sb2.append("field3   FROM table1; ");
String str = sb2.toString();
```

Not only does it create multiple `StringBuilder` instances and do unnecessary calls to `toString`, but it uses the default constructor, which only allocates enough room for a 16-character string in its array (last I checked). So `StringBuilder` will probably have to reallocate its internal array at *least* once. Blech, right? (Wait for it...)

Compare with what you could do yourself:

```
String str = (new StringBuilder(200))
                .append(" SELECT " +
                        "field1, ")
                .append(someVariable)
                .append("field3  " +
                        " FROM table1; ")
                .toString();
```

That's much more efficient.

But is it ***better***? It's awful to look at and awful to maintain. You'd have to be doing it in a tight loop for it to matter from a performance perspective.

So it's "better" if you have a performance problem that this helps solve.

It's not "better" if you don't, as the code is much less clear.

None of which matters if you're dealing with literals only.

Comment: what u say about @jesper 's answer

Comment: @murtaza.webdev: I think it's incomplete. The entire second part of my answer above is there for a reason. My guess is that you're **not** just using string literals, and if you aren't, that's what the second part of my answer is about.

Answer (score 1):

`+` is considered bad when you concatenate Strings in loop. Lets say you have

```
String s = "f";
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    s = s + "o";
}
```

In this case

```
s = s + "o";
```

will be compiled as

```
s = new StringBuilder(f).append("o").toString();
```

so in each iteration you are creating new StringBuilder, you are copying current content of `s` to it, then you are adding `o` and recreate new String instance by calling `toString` which you are storing in `s` reference. As you see that is lot of things to do, especially coppying and creating new instance of String, which time to execution depends on length of string.

Preferred way to do it would be creating your own StringBuilder, appending what you want in loop, and after end of loop creating new String object from content of StringBuilder. Something like

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("f");
for (int i=0; i<100; i++){
    sb.append("o");
}
String s = sb.toString();
```

---

But in your case since you are operating on compile-time-constant which can't be changed so compiler is able to figure out that

```
String str = " SELECT "
           + "field1, "
           + "field2, "
           + "field3  "
           + " FROM table1; ";
```

can be nothing else than `" SELECT field1, field2, field3   FROM table1; "` so it will be concatenated at compilation time so your str will be compiled as

```
String str = " SELECT field1, field2, field3   FROM table1; ";
```

Comment: what u say about @jesper 's answer

Comment: @murtaza.webdev It is correct. Concatenation of compilation-time-constants can be done at compile time, like `String result = "foo"+"bar"`, will result in same bytecode as `String result = "foobar"`, but it will not work same way for `String s1 = "foo"; String s2 = "bar"; String result = s1 + s2;` nor `String result = "foo"+s2;` (because `s1` and `s2` are not compilation-time-constants here), in that case result will have to be generated at runtime and compiler will change your code to use `StringBuilder`.

Answer (score 1):

What you're doing here isn't really wrong. It is awkward though, for these reasons:

- Illegibility: all the operators and quotes make this annoying to read
- Error-prone: it's too easy when modifying this to omit a space from a substring and break the query
- Inconvenient: you can't copy a query into a SQL tool without having to stop and remove all the operators and quotes.

You could extract SQL like this into a configuration file, either a properties file or XML (using CDATA) could work. You can see examples at [Spring Integration - Externalizing JDBC Queries](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25556825/217324)